# Strapi 2FA availability

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, authentication, strapi

I have my backend done in `Strapi` and I want to make `2FA/MFA`.
I wonder if there is any possible solution since I wasn't able to find any.

*I was searching for some solutions, but all I was able to find on Stack was in version 3.x.x and all links expired.*

I know there are providers for logging/signing in but I am using only the built-in *Email* provider.

**Functionality**- I want my users to be able to Log in and then verify it's them, either by confirmation code in a third-party app `(Google Authenticator, Duo...)` or `confirmation code from their email.`

Thanks for the help in advance ❤️

> *Using Strapi v4.2.2*

Comment: Found out there is nothing like that available in the bare Strapi. Although I was able to edit the controller a bit and managed to assemble it. Not hard and there is plenty of tutorials on YT if u not familiar with node :)